# Re-Opening a BerkeleyDB database raises a Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, berkeley-db

In the following program, I

- open a BDB environment
- open a database  DB_BTREE/DB_CREATE
- close the database
- reopen the database as DB_UNKNOWN/DB_RDONLY ...

but it raises an segmentation fault.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008e4 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe888) at testbdb.c:38
38                  if ((ret = dbp1->open(dbp1,
```

why ?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <db.h>



int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
    DB_ENV *dbenv=NULL;
        DB *dbp1=NULL;
        int ret;
        int i;
        if(argc!=2) return -1;

        if ((ret = db_env_create(&dbenv, 0)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", argv[0], db_strerror(ret));
            exit(-1);
        }


        if ((ret =
            dbenv->open(dbenv, argv[1], DB_CREATE | DB_INIT_MPOOL, 0)) != 0) {
            dbenv->err(dbenv, ret, "environment open: %s", argv[1]);
            exit(-1);
        }


        if ((ret = db_create(&dbp1, dbenv, 0)) != 0) {
            dbenv->err(dbenv, ret, "database create");
            exit(-1);
        }
        for( i=0;i<2;++i)
                {
                printf("open i=%d\n",i);
                if ((ret = dbp1->open(dbp1,
                        NULL,
                        "database1", "database1",
                        (i==0?DB_BTREE:DB_UNKNOWN),
                        (i==0?DB_CREATE:DB_RDONLY),
                        0)) != 0) {
                    dbenv->err(dbenv, ret, "DB->open: database1");
                     exit(-1);
                    }

                dbp1->close(dbp1, 0);
                printf("close i=%d\n",i);
                }


    (void)dbenv->close(dbenv, 0);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Just wondering... is there a reason why you're writing new code with Berkeley DB in 2011? These days we have sqlite which is still light but much more powerful and lacks the design flaws and limitations of libdbm...

Comment: big data :-)  http://www.sciencemag.org/content/331/6018.cover-expansion

Comment: I don't think I'd use Berkeley DB for "big data" (or for any data, for that matter...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation of the close() function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/dbclose.html) "The DB handle may not be accessed again after DB->close() is called" which is what your loop is doing. That's probably a good place to start looking.